# Как убрать ошибку TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WebDriver' and 'str'?

Tags: python

пытаюсь писать тесты в Selenium WebDriver  есть такая фикстура:

```
  def pytest_addoption(parser):
      parser.addoption("--bwr", action="store", default="chrome", choices=["ie", "firefox", "chrome"])
      parser.addoption("--burl", action="store", default="https://demodemo.com/")

@pytest.fixture
def browse(request):
    browser = request.config.getoption("--bwr")
    url = request.config.getoption("--burl")
    driver = "chrome"

        browser == "chrome":
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        if headless: options.headless = True
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

есть код:

```
class PageAdmin:
    path = "/admin/"

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def admpage_open(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url + self.path)
```

И к нему тест на открытие страницы:

```
  def test_adm_view(browse):
    admin_page = PageAdmin(browse)
    admin_page.admpage_open(browse)
```

По выполнению возникает такая ошибка:

```
def admpage_open(self, url):
```

> ```
>   self.driver.get(url + self.path)
> ```

E       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WebDriver' and 'str'

Видимо что-то элементарное, но видимо зациклился не могу понять как исправить. Заранее спасибо

Comment: А если `.get(str(url) + self.path)` ? Или перед этой строчкой пробуйте запустить `print(dir(url))`, возможно там найдется нужное свойство.

Comment: По тексту ошибки можно понять, что вы пытаетесь сложить два не совсем совместимых объекта.
Возможно в каком-то JS у вас бы получилось это сделать - тут нет.